# What is the differences in time manipulation between array_intersect_key and array_diff_key?

Tags: php, performance, oop

```
$arr1 = ['value1','value2','value3','value4']; 
$arr2 = ['value1','value3'];
```

my function return true if at least one intersect value will be fined on :

```
function is_array_intersect($arr1,$arr2) {
    $arr1 = array_flip($arr1);
    $arr2 = array_flip($arr2);
    $intersectArr = array_intersect_key($arr1,$arr2);
    if (count($intersectArr)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false
}
```

is there better way to implement this function with minimum manipulation time?

Comment: Just use `array_intersect()` and then you don't have to flip your arrays.

Answer (score 1):

This can be simplified.

```
$arr1 = ['value1','value2','value3','value4']; 
$arr2 = ['value1','value3'];
$arr3 = ['value1a','value3'];
$arr4 = ['value1a','value3a'];

echo "is_array_intersect()\n";
echo "arr2 = " . (is_array_intersect($arr1,$arr2) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE') . "\n";
echo "arr3 = " . (is_array_intersect($arr1,$arr3) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE') . "\n";
echo "arr4 = " . (is_array_intersect($arr1,$arr4) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE') . "\n";

echo "is_array_intersect2()\n";
echo "arr2 = " . (is_array_intersect2($arr1,$arr2) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE') . "\n";
echo "arr3 = " . (is_array_intersect2($arr1,$arr3) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE') . "\n";
echo "arr4 = " . (is_array_intersect2($arr1,$arr4) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE') . "\n";


function is_array_intersect($arr1,$arr2) {
    $arr1 = array_flip($arr1);
    $arr2 = array_flip($arr2);
    $intersectArr = array_intersect_key($arr1,$arr2);
    if (count($intersectArr)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function is_array_intersect2($arr1,$arr2) {
    return count(array_intersect($arr1,$arr2)) > 0;
}
```

Output:

```
is_array_intersect()
arr2 = TRUE
arr3 = TRUE
arr4 = FALSE
is_array_intersect2()
arr2 = TRUE
arr3 = TRUE
arr4 = FALSE
```

See the code in action: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/912306c093a9dcc3b760cd6c84bdd95c0595b19b

Comment: No need to call `array_keys()` here.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should not be using the key here, but the values.

Well, in Set Theory, *diff* and *intersect* are two different operations.

According to the manual:

[array_diff](http://php.net/array_diff)

```
array array_diff ( array $array1 , array $array2 [, array $... ] )
```

> Compares array1 against one or more other arrays and **returns the
>   values in array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays**.

[array_intersect](http://php.net/array_intersect)

```
array array_intersect ( array $array1 , array $array2 [, array $... ] )
```

> array_intersect() **returns an array containing all the values of array1
>   that are present in all the arguments**. Note that keys are preserved.

So, the function that suits you here is `array_intersect`. Then you could rewrite your function as:

```
function is_array_intersect(array $arr1, array $arr2) {
    return count(array_intersect($arr1, $arr2)) > 0;
}
```